# Horizontal alignment of tikzpicure in an equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, equations

In this minimal working example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \lambda =  \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(1cm,0) -- (2cm,0);
\draw(2cm,0) -- (3cm,0);
\draw(1cm,0)[fill=white]circle(.06cm);
\draw(2cm,0)[fill=white]circle(.06cm);
\draw(3cm,0)[fill=white]circle(.06cm);
\node[below]at(2cm,0){\scriptsize $\alpha_2$};
\end{tikzpicture} \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

how can I align horizontally lambda and the lines in the tikzpicure?
(equation (1) in the picture.)

If I remove the line

```
\node[below]at(2cm,0){\scriptsize $\alpha_2$};
```

or put [above] in place of [below], then everything is aligned as I want (equations (2) and (3) in the picture), but I want to keep the node below. Also, I would not want to put lambda inside the tikzpicture.

[image: aling horizontally equation (1)]

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that in the theory I am writing about, \node[above] has different meaning than \node[below].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the half of the height of the node content (roughly) to adjust the baseline

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
\lambda =  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,{-0.5*height("$\alpha_2$")*1pt})}]
\draw(1,0) -- (3,0) node[below,midway]{$\scriptstyle\alpha_2$};
\draw[fill=white]foreach\x in{1,2,3}{(\x cm,0)circle(.06cm)};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]