# Vertical alignment of tikz circle in equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I wish to insert a graphic in an equation, and have it horizontally centered.

For example, the circle in the following example should be in the center of the brackets, not sitting halfway above them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  A + B \Big \langle \tikz \draw (0,0) circle (0.5cm); \Big \rangle
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

How do I achieve this?

I'm aware of the hack [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255001/), but find this unsuitable. (It will be impractical for me to hack 50+ such diagrams by hand.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard way to center content in math is `\vcenter` which alignes a list of vertical material centered to the math axis (the invisible line the minus sign, the equal sign, fractions etc. are aligned):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  A + B \Big \langle \vcenter{\hbox{\tikz \draw (0,0) circle (0.5cm);}} \Big \rangle
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is still worth mentioning that `baseline` can help you in an efficient way: by defining a style `vertical align` that abbreviates the long `baseline=...` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        vertical align/.style={
            baseline=-.5*(height("$+$")-depth("$+$"))
        }
    }
    \foreach\size in{\tiny,\footnotesize,\normalsize,\Large,\huge}{
        \size
        \begin{equation}
            A+B\Big\langle\tikz[vertical align]\draw circle(0.5);\Big\rangle^{
            A+B\Big\langle\tikz[vertical align]\draw circle(0.5);\Big\rangle^{
            A+B\Big\langle\tikz[vertical align]\draw circle(0.5);\Big\rangle}}
        \end{equation}
    }
    \end{document}
```

---

What can be done further is that you can apply style globally by saying

```
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={vertical align}
}
```

For irrelevant pictures, you can cancel the effect by either grouping or saying `[baseline=0pt]` or just `[baseline]`. (Or you can define `no vertical align/.style={baseline}`)

---

You can also encode the drawing of the circle in a `.pic`. For example

```
\tikzset{
    cir5/.pic={
        \draw circle(0.5);
    }
}
```

Together with the global setting of `baseline`, the code is now much simpler

```
    \begin{equation}
          A+B\Big\langle\tikz\pic{cir5};\Big\rangle
    \end{equation}
```

in contrast to

```
    \begin{equation}
        A+B\Big\langle\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz\draw circle(0.5);}}\Big\rangle
    \end{equation}
```

---

Of course one can do something like `\def\vcentertikz#1{\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz{#1}}}}`, just like one can do `\def\tikzvcenterpic#1{\tikz[vcenter]{\pic{#1}}}`. So as long as one does not need tricky baseline setting (such as `baseline=(node.anchor)`), both methods are interchangeable.

---

The following is the full code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        vertical align/.style={
            baseline=-.5*(height("$+$")-depth("$+$"))
        }
    }
    \foreach\size in{\tiny,\footnotesize,\normalsize,\Large,\huge}{
        \size
        \begin{equation}
            A+B\Big\langle\tikz[vertical align]\draw circle(0.5);\Big\rangle^{
            A+B\Big\langle\tikz[vertical align]\draw circle(0.5);\Big\rangle^{
            A+B\Big\langle\tikz[vertical align]\draw circle(0.5);\Big\rangle}}
        \end{equation}
    }

    \clearpage

    \tikzset{
        every picture/.style={vertical align}
    }
    \foreach\size in{\tiny,\footnotesize,\normalsize,\Large,\huge}{
        \size
        \begin{equation}
            A+B\Big\langle\tikz\draw circle(0.5);\Big\rangle^{
            A+B\Big\langle\tikz\draw circle(0.5);\Big\rangle^{
            A+B\Big\langle\tikz\draw circle(0.5);\Big\rangle}}
        \end{equation}
    }

    \clearpage

    \tikzset{
        cir5/.pic={
            \draw circle(0.5);
        }
    }
    \foreach\size in{\tiny,\footnotesize,\normalsize,\Large,\huge}{
        \size
        \begin{equation}
              A+B\Big\langle\tikz\pic{cir5};\Big\rangle
            ^{A+B\Big\langle\tikz\pic{cir5};\Big\rangle
            ^{A+B\Big\langle\tikz\pic{cir5};\Big\rangle}}
        \end{equation}
    }

    \clearpage

    \foreach\size in{\tiny,\footnotesize,\normalsize,\Large,\huge}{
        \size
        \begin{equation}
            A + B \Big \langle \vcenter{\hbox{\tikz \draw (0,0) circle (0.5cm);}} \Big \rangle^{
            A + B \Big \langle \vcenter{\hbox{\tikz \draw (0,0) circle (0.5cm);}} \Big \rangle^{
            A + B \Big \langle \vcenter{\hbox{\tikz \draw (0,0) circle (0.5cm);}} \Big \rangle}}
        \end{equation}
    }

\end{document}
```