# Align vertically 2 circuits

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, circuitikz

I'm currently at 8th grade working on circuits and I'm taking notes with LaTeX and CircuiTi*k*Z. The problem is that I have 2 circuits, but one is vertically bigger than the other, and so I don't know how to align those two circuits vertically.

Currently I have this code:

```
\begin{center}\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) to[R, l=$R_1$] (3,1) -- (3,0) -- (4,0);
\draw (1,0) -- (1,-1) to[R, l=$R_2$] (3,-1) -- (3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
$\ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ $
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[R, l=$R$] (3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
$$R=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}} \Longleftrightarrow R=\left( \sum_n\frac{1}{R_n} \right)^{-1}$$
```

### [image]

Then I tried adding a node at `(4,0)` and add the second circuit but I get this:

```
\begin{center}\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) to[R, l=$R_1$] (3,1) -- (3,0) -- (4,0);
\draw (1,0) -- (1,-1) to[R, l=$R_2$] (3,-1) -- (3,0);
\draw (4,0) node[right]{$\ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ $
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[R, l=$R$] (3,0);
\end{circuitikz}};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Anyone knows how could I align the circuits?

Comment: `$$` is not supported in LaTeX, use `\[` and `\]` instead!, also instead of nesting two `circuitikz` environments (or putting them next to each other), simply draw both circuits in the same environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this could look like this (I'd personally work more with relative placement than this, but this might do for OP).

The used `scope`s are not necessary for this, I only added them for semantic reasons and they could be dropped.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \begin{scope} % not really necessary
      \draw (0,0) to[short,-*] (1,0) -- (1,1) to[R, l=$R_1$] (3,1) to[short,-*]
        (3,0) -- (4,0) coordinate(end1);
      \draw (1,0) -- (1,-1) to[R, l=$R_2$] (3,-1) -- (3,0);
    \end{scope}
    \path
      (end1)++(0.5,0)
      node[anchor=west](lr){$\Longleftrightarrow$}
      ;
    \begin{scope} % not really necessary
      \draw (lr.east)++(.5,0) to[R, l=$R$] ++(3,0);
    \end{scope}
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\[
  R = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}} \Longleftrightarrow R
    = \left( \sum_n\frac{1}{R_n} \right)^{-1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps with a `TikZ` matrix, one could get a more aesthetic result with formulas centred under their circuit.

Comment: @projetmbc the formulae are not directly linked to either of the circuits, both fully describe the two circuits and how they are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

Although I would use [@Skillmon method here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678320/38080) (centering the arrow would be quite complex here, see [Vertical alignment of tikz circle in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334732/vertical-alignment-of-tikz-circle-in-equation), for example), is good to know the existence of [the `baseline` option to Ti*k*Z](https://tikz.dev/tikz-scopes#tikz/baseline) (and so `circuitikz`) pictures. You can feed it a coordinate or a node, and it will consider this coordinate or node the vertical position around which the whole picture is aligned vertically.

```latex
\documentclass[border=3.14,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
      \begin{circuitikz}[baseline={(0,0)}]
      \draw (0,0) to[short,-*] (1,0) -- (1,1) to[R, l=$R_1$] (3,1) to[short,-*]
        (3,0) -- (4,0) coordinate(end1);
      \draw (1,0) -- (1,-1) to[R, l=$R_2$] (3,-1) -- (3,0);
  \end{circuitikz}\quad
  \tikz [baseline] \draw (0,0) node{$\Longleftrightarrow$};
  \quad
  \begin{circuitikz}[baseline={(0,0)}]
      \draw (0,0) to[R, l=$R$] ++(3,0);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\[
  R = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}} \Longleftrightarrow R
    = \left( \sum_n\frac{1}{R_n} \right)^{-1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could align the arrows using saveboxes, \hphantom, \mathllap and \mathrlap (mathtools).